# LDAP and PHP connection failure

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to connect to a secure LDAP server (using LDAPs) via PHP, but I am having problems with it. I get the following error

> Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/test.php on line 16

I works when I try to connect without LDAPs, but it is required that I use LDAPs because I am going to be dealing with sensitive information.

I am using the following code

```
<?php
// basic sequence with LDAP is connect, bind, search, interpret search
// result, close connection

echo "<h3>LDAP query test</h3>";
echo "Connecting ...";
$ds=ldap_connect("ldaps://server");  // must be a valid LDAP server!




print $ds;

if ($ds) { 
    echo "<br><br>Binding ..."; 
    $r=ldap_bind($ds);     // this is an "anonymous" bind, typically
                           // read-only access
    echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";

    echo "Searching for (sn=S*) ...";
    // Search surname entry
    $sr=ldap_search($ds, "ou=people,o=server.ca,o=server", "uid=username*");  
    echo "Search result is " . $sr . "<br />";

    echo "Number of entires returned is " . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br />";

    echo "Getting entries ...<p>";
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
    echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";

print_r($info);
//    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
//        echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
//        echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
//        echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
//    }

    echo "Closing connection";
    ldap_close($ds);

} else {
    echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but is "ldaps://server" a valid LDAP server?  That doesn't look like a valid URI to me...

Comment: Its a valid server. I didnt write the real servername there for security purposes

Comment: sorry, I never actually resolved this problem

Comment: Is this issue still unresolved?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is not related to the actual binding process (invalid credentials) as the warning would be a different one if the LDAP server could not authenticate your credentials. But as [Paul Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049653/ldap-and-php/1050061#1050061) noted the use of `ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)` should be required - even though I don't think that this is the cause of your problems.

- Which LDAP server type are you connecting to? OpenLDAP, Active Directory or something else?
- What's the operating system of the computer running your PHP program?
- Are you using a self-signed SSL certificate on the LDAP server and is the certificate authority for the given certificate trusted by the machine running your PHP program?
- Which port does the LDAP server run on? 636 would be the "official" port for LDAPS. Perhaps you can add the port explicitly to the server address: `ldaps://<<server>>:636`.

`ext/ldap` has some issues with SSL/TLS secured connections. You can try to add

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

to the `ldap.conf` (`/etc/ldap.conf` or `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` on *nix-based systems) or for Windows machines create a `ldap.conf` with the above content in `C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf\ldap.conf` (the path must be an exact match as it's hard-coded into the extension).

Comment: This option can also be set via LDAP initialisation options (on python anyway, ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER))

Comment: IMO, this is very bad advice for anything beyond simple debugging. Setting TLS_REQCERT to never will disable all TLS certificate checking. This defeats the entire purpose of using TLS in the first place. With this option set, there is no guarantee the connection is secure.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a problem using SSL/TLS on some servers with recent PHP versions. Not sure why. You can refer to my post at: [Problems with secure bind to Active Directory using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258556/problems-with-secure-bind-to-active-directory-using-php)

One of the more likely causes, is the cause from Stefan. To make sure that this is really the case, you can use:

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
```

before your ldap_connect. This will print a more sane error message to log (typically ssl cert not valid, ref. Stefan Gehrig)

Answer (score 2):

Although old, I have encountered the same issue and wanted to provide some insight for future readers.

Part of the problem was out-of-date OpenSSL libraries, 0.9.6 vs 1.0.0 (which worked).

After updating OpenSSL on the server, it was noted that PHP lost support for OpenSSL.

You can check support for modules with the following from the command line:

```
php -m
```

Or

```
echo phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
```

From the browser.

Also, there have been a lot of issues with SSL Support for LDAP when using the OCI8/Oracle LDAP libs in my professional experience. On Debian platforms, Libldap-2.4.2-dev packages work best.

Additionally, you should look at the connection logs on the LDAP server. I can almost guarantee that you will see an error referring to SSLv3 and missing a CA for the certificate.

By default, PHP looks for the CA file on UNIX systems in, make sure it is readable by the PHP invoker (user via cli, Apache user, etc..):

```
/etc/pki/CA
```

This is not necessarily a PHP issue, but a configuration issue with Secure LDAP. Please see this [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18049) and this [OpenLDAP thread](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200108/msg00043.html).

The OpenLDAP thread above has a snippet of a working OpenLDAP config for reference.

Some other things to check is your services definitions in /etc/services. Make sure you have the following:

```
ldaps           636/tcp                         # LDAP over SSL
ldaps           636/udp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the ldap protocol version to be 3

```
echo "<h3>LDAP query test</h3>";
echo "Connecting ...";

$ldap_server = 'ldaps://server';
$ldap_port = '636';

$ds = ldap_connect($ldap_server, $ldap_port);

if ($ds) 
{
    //add this
    if (!ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)) 
    {
        fatal_error("Failed to set LDAP Protocol version to 3, TLS not supported.");
    }
    echo "<br><br>Binding ..."; 
    $r=ldap_bind($ds);     // this is an "anonymous" bind, typically
                       // read-only access
    echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";

    echo "Searching for (sn=S*) ...";
    // Search surname entry
    $sr=ldap_search($ds, "ou=people,o=server.ca,o=server", "uid=username*");  
    echo "Search result is " . $sr . "<br />";

    echo "Number of entires returned is " . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br />";

    echo "Getting entries ...<p>";
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
    echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";

    print_r($info);
    //    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
    //        echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
    //        echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
    //        echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
    //    }

    echo "Closing connection";
    ldap_close($ds);

} 
else 
{
    echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}
```

Comment: sorry, this didnt work. It never threw your error message, nor did it bind porperly

Answer (score 0):

On UNIX "man ldap.conf" = ... SYNOPSIS /usr/local/etc/openldap/ldap.conf ...

Write **TLS_REQCERT never** in /usr/local/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
and set ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)

This work in my project on Nginx+PHP-fpm:
nginx/1.6.0
php55-5.5.15
php55-ldap-5.5.15
openldap-client-2.4.39_1

Answer (score 0):

What saved my day after reading and trying out solutions from allover the web and SO, was to **use a ldaps uri without the port** specified in it.

So instead of this: `ldaps://example.com:636` I had to use this: `ldaps://example.com` and it now works like a charm.

I was setting this up on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP7.3 runing through Nginx and php-fpm.

A full code example:

```
try{
    $ldapUri = "ldaps://example.com";
    $ldapUsername = 'username';
    $ldapPassword = 'password';
    $ldapConn = ldap_connect($ldapUri);
    if($ldapConn){
        ldap_set_option($ldapConn,LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,10);

        if(!ldap_set_option($ldapConn,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)){
           print 'Failed to set ldap protocol to version 3<br>';
        }
        ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
        $ldapBind = ldap_bind($ldapConn, $ldapUsername, $ldapPass);
        if ($ldapBind) {
           echo "LDAP bind successful...";
           //DO LDAP search and stuff
           ldap_unbind($ldapConn);
        } else {
           echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        }
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    print($e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable "anonymous binds" on your LDAP-Server or use a correct bind (username / password).

like `cn=ldapauthuser,ou=accounts,dc=example,dc=com`