# Active Directory on local server and intranet on external server

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, external, local

I have a local Active Directory server and a external web server where my intranet is located.

```
$ad = ldap_connect("ldap://ip-address") or die("Couldn't connect to AD!");
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$bd = ldap_bind( $ad, "user@domain", "password") or die("Can't bind to server.");
```

When I run this on a local web server it succesfully binds the connection. If I run the same code on the external server its unable to bind the ldap connection. Both port 389 and 636 is open on the AD server.

I've tried google for an answer, but all the tutorials is for Active Directory and webserver on the same server. Is this even possible?

Comment: Firewall? Try to telnet from the remote server to see what happens: telnet ip-address 389

Comment: thanks! port 389 and 636 is now open. :) 

ldap_connect("ip-address") now works, but ldap_connect("ldaps://ip-address", 636) dosn't. Anyone knows why? o_O

It gives me this error:
Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding LDAPS, this is often related to an invalid ssl certificate. A workaround for that is described here: [LDAP and PHP connection failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049653/ldap-and-php/5452223#5452223)