# How to read contact information from office add-in in word

Tags: vsto, office-js, office-addins

I need to have an office add-in component (https://dev.office.com/getting-started/addins ) to allow user to select a contact from the global address book to insert that contact email in the word document.

Any suggestions if this can be done with office add-ins? if yes how can it be done? or it must be VSTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/) is simply a web app (that happens to run in the context of an Office host), so you can design it to do the types of things that a web app can do, including issuing requests against REST APIs. Regarding the scenario you've described, I'd view it as 3 distinct tasks:

1. Get contact info from AD.
2. Present list of contacts to user (so they can select one).
3. Insert email address of selected contact into document.

**1- Getting contact info:**

Re the specific scenario that you've described, I'd suggest that you investigate the feasibility of using either the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/azure_ad_overview) or the [Azure Active Directory Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) to get contact information from the GAL. Please note that, in general, [using Microsoft Graph is recommended over using Azure AD Graph](https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph).

**2- Presenting list of contacts to the User:**

Regarding UI design, because your Office Add-in is simply a web app, you can present the list of contacts to the user in whatever manner that your web app supports.

**3- Inserting text into the Word document:**

Regarding inserting text into the document when the user selects a contact via the Add-in UI, you'll use the [Word JavaScript API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview) to do this. If you haven't used the Word JavaScript API before, I'd suggest that you start by doing the [Word Add-in quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart), which shows how to insert text at various points in a document. Then, for additional details about the API, see the [Word JavaScript API reference docs](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview). (Which API operation you use to insert text into the document will depend the specifics of your implementation. I'd suggest that you post a separate Stack Overflow question that describes specifically what you want to achieve re insertion of text into the document, if you need help with that when the time comes.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. about #1: "Getting contact info:" any suggestion for getting this information from a local AD (i.e. client not using office365 or Azure AD).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with querying AD, but perhaps these other posts might be helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813452/connect-to-active-directory-via-ldap  OR  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780587/active-directory-on-local-server-and-intranet-on-external-server