# Php adLDAP Error - Unable to bind to server: Strong(er) authentication required

Tags: php, openssl, ldap, domaincontroller, adldap

I am attempting to use [PHP adLDAP version 4.04](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/)  to authenticate on a corporate network with no success yet.

`PHP Version 5.2.4`

I tried this stackoverflow post [PHP ldap - Strong(er) authentication required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991591/php-ldap-stronger-authentication-required), no luck.

I am **NOT** an admin on this domain controller; I only need to be able to query.

I am able to ping `HOSTNAMEOFDC.domain.location.company.com` (the FQDN of my Domain Controller)

The domain controller is a `Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard`.

I have successfully queried this domain controller using `DsQuery` and `PowerShell AD Module` with no problem and no authentication that I had to manually type.

My code:

```
<?php
require_once("includes/php/adLDAP/src/adLDAP.php");
$username = "domain\\username"; // also tried just "username"
$password = "somepassword";

// All possible settings are listed in this array
$options = array(
        "account_suffix" => "@domain.location.company.com",
//      "admin_username" => $username,
//      "admin_password" => $password,
//      "ad_port" => "636",
//      "base_dn" => "DC=domain,DC=location,DC=company,DC=com",
        "domain_controllers" => array("HOSTNAMEOFDC.domain.location.company.com"),
//      "real_primarygroup" => "",
//      "recursive_groups" => "",
//      "use_ssl" => true
//      "use_tls" => true
);

$adldap = new adLDAP($options);


// $authUser = $adldap->user()->authenticate($username, $password);
$authUser = $adldap->user()->authenticate($username,$password);
if ($authUser) {
    echo "User authenticated successfully";
} else {
    // getLastError is not needed, but may be helpful for finding out why:
    echo $adldap->getLastError() . "<br>";
    echo "User authentication unsuccessful";
}

// Destroy
$adldap->close();
$adldap->__destruct();
?>
```

I get the error:

```
Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Strong(er) authentication required in C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\Project\scripts\includes\php\adLDAP\src\adLDAP.php on line 712
Strong(er) authentication required
User authentication unsuccessful
```

Then when I uncomment `"use_ssl" => true"` I get this error:

FYI, `ssl` is loaded in my `php.ini`

```
Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\Project\scripts\includes\php\adLDAP\src\adLDAP.php on line 712
Can't contact LDAP server
User authentication unsuccessful
```

I've also tried uncommenting `"use_tls" => true"` and I get this error:

```
Warning: ldap_start_tls() [function.ldap-start-tls]: Unable to start TLS: Connect error in C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\Project\scripts\includes\php\adLDAP\src\adLDAP.php on line 638

Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\Project\scripts\includes\php\adLDAP\src\adLDAP.php on line 712
Can't contact LDAP server
User authentication unsuccessful
```

Comment: Ldap bind is done with the rdn not username, although servers can be configured to accept username. And check your protocol version too, some will need to be set to version 3

Comment: @frz3993 Excuse my newb-ary, what would be an example RDN? Like `Doman\username`?

Comment: More like a component of DN like `uid=12345, ou=people`. Some server allow domain\username. But I dont think this is the problem

Comment: @frz3993 I solved this if you are interested in the outcome. Probably took 10 hours or so to get this solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This answer is pertaining to PHP 5.2 -5.3, this bug has been fixed in newer versions (probably)**

Annoyingly, when PHP spits back the error *Unable to bind to server: Strong(er) authentication required* - it is actually telling you that it needs a certificate or group of certificates **ON YOUR LOCAL MACHINE** and have a `.conf` file point to them.

I created a directory: `C:\openldap\sysconf` (it did not exist prior).

I made the file  `ldap.conf` in `C:\openldap\sysconf`

In *nix you would probably put it in `/etc` or a subdir in there, but I have not tested that yet.

I went and found the PEM file for our certs and extracted it in the directory (a PEM file is basically the whole chain of certs in one file).

Within `ldap.conf` I added the line: `TLS_CACERT C:\openldap\sysconf\Certs.pem`

If you cannot get the PEM certs, you can use `TLS_REQCERT never` instead. **Be careful when doing this. You expose yourself to a man in the middle attack by doing this. It will not validate the endpoint.**

Once I did this, I successfully binded.

If that doesn't work, try putting `ldap.conf` in `C:\` (root level); it seems to depend on what version of PHP you are using - it decides to look in different places for `ldap.conf`.